# Why are non-trainable parameters zero in model's summary, despite loading the weights of the model?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, transfer-learning, pre-trained-model

I used the command

```
torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'model.pth')
```

to save the parameters after training the model.
But, when I use the commands

```
model = EfficientNetModel()
MODEL_PATH = 'model.pth'
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(MODEL_PATH, map_location=map_location))
model.eval()
summary(model,(1,224,224) )
```

to load the pre-trained weights, the number of non-trainable parameters is 0, as per the attached screenshot.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47abG.png)

Why is it happening and how can I rectify this?

Thank You

Comment: Were you expecting this model to have *non-trainable params*?

Comment: @Ivan, Since I had trained the model, saved the weights and then loaded the saved weights, I was thinking that all of the parameters should be non-trainable. But, since I am new to PyTorch and Deep Learning, I'm unsure if what I'm thinking is correct. Please rectify me if my thinking is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Saving and loading weights back on a model doesn't affect the fact they are *trainable* or not. Nontrainable params contain tensors that do not require gradient computation, and as such won't get modified by your optimizer during training.